# Width/Length of a Mosfet in LTSpice on Macbook

Tags: mosfet, ltspice

In order to change the width and length of a mosfet gate in LTSpice on Windows you just right click on the device, but how do you accomplish this on a Macbook?

Comment: What if you double click on the device?

Comment: I ask this because I do not have a Mac.

Comment: Command-click on OSX is usually the equivalent of right-click on Windows. Does that not work?

Comment: Command-click doesn't pop up any window, command-right click pops up a window to edit the naming of the device, double click doesn't pop up any window